# How to push elements "off screen" using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to design a mobile website and I have been using W3schools for guidance. I successfully implemented a simple side menu from W3Schools, however, when in mobile view it pushes an image below and not off the screen.

How would I change this, as I want to push all contents of the div of screen and not squash them.

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_shift - this is the example I am using. I want to push the car image off the screen and not shrink it.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Dean

Comment: have you tried this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

Comment: When viewing it mobile, what is your screen resolution? And when you say: 'as I want to push all contents of the div of screen and not squash them', could I translate that as 'I want to hide all content in the right column'?

Comment: Rather than using `margin-left:25%` for the open state, use `transform:translateX(25%)` instead. You'll also need to change the `transition` rule to use `transform` instead of `margin-left`. This will give the effect you want.

Comment: try removing width:100% from the image

Comment: What do you mean by mobile view specifically? A mobile viewport of 320px is not the same of a 450px one, that is obvious. You also need to consider the side menu on smaller viewports will make the content of the page even smaller and this will have implications for UX/UI. Try to use `@media only screen queries` and to follow best practices for menus on smaller viewports, such as perhaps dynamically change the side menu to visible anchor tags or links in your header

Comment: @D-shore have you tried my answer? Does it fit your needs?

Comment: @fcalderan, your solution worked perfectly! Apologies for the long delay in my response, something came up and I was not around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this effect in several ways: in this example the basic idea is to place side-by-side two elements having their total width greater than 100% (for example with flexbox).

Then apply a negative `margin-left` to the menu element (`aside`) so to place it off-screen and set the margin to `0` (with a CSS transition) to show it.

The button belongs to the menu element, but it is visually placed on the content area with an `absolute` position and a negative `right` offset.

---

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('aside');
let menuBtt = menu.querySelector('button');
menuBtt.addEventListener('click', ()=>menu.classList.toggle('visible'));
```

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

aside, main { 
  box-sizing: border-box; }

aside {  
  position: relative;
  min-width: 250px; 
  margin-left: -250px;
  transition: margin .4s; }

main  {  min-width: 100%;  }

aside button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .4s;
}

aside.visible {
  margin-left: 0; 
}



aside.visible button {
   color: #62616c; }






aside  { background: #f2f2f2; font: 1.1rem/1.3 Arial; padding: 10px; }
aside button:focus { outline: 0; }
h2 { margin: 0; }
main { font: 0.9rem/1.6 Arial; padding: 60px 20px; }
main img { width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="menu">
    <button>&#x2630;</button>
    
     <h2>Main Menu</h2>
     
   </aside>

  <main>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/320" /> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac dictum justo. Integer venenatis orci sed nulla malesuada finibus. Maecenas tellus metus, porta nec euismod quis, pellentesque vitae enim. Pellentesque id metus condimentum, aliquet lorem eget, pretium magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras luctus leo id turpis interdum, eu fermentum elit auctor. Nulla ornare accumsan elit a scelerisque. Nam a dolor nec orci condimentum dignissim ac eget justo. Donec ligula quam, sagittis vel pretium et, auctor at odio. Quisque laoreet feugiat elit. Mauris sit amet urna vel risus mattis pharetra.</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `margin-left:25%` changes the (implied) width to `75%`, resulting in a smaller content area. This interferes with your text layout as well as the image's size.

Consider instead using `transform:translateX(25%)` or even `position:relative; left:25%` - both of these will produce the same result: shifting the content by 25% of the width (albeit in different ways).

You will of course need to change the `transition` from `margin-left 4s` to `transform .4s` or `left .4s` as desired.